# Risks when running a MySQL Galera Cluster in production without binlogs?

Tags: mariadb, galera

First of all: I assume that this is no real good idea.

However, this Bug in MariaDB 10.1.xx crashes single cluster nodes.

https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-9510

One of the workarounds is to disable the binlogs.

I personally think, that this comes with a lot of other risks, like inconsistent databases or not being able to get the database into a consistent state after restarting.

I need to understand the risks and drawbacks before eventually taking the decision to disable the binlogs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MDEV-9510](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-9510) has been resolved in  10.1.30, 10.2.11 and all later versions.

Answer (score 1):

As per as best practices for setting up MySQL Galera cluster , it is compulsory to enable binary logs and binlog format as ROW.

Not sure why you are interested in disabling binlogs , few are the disadvantages:

- unable to debug queries
- unable to setup a replica server if required.